# Tablesorter Default Sort On 2 Columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I have 2 columns, One holding dates and the other event names. I'm trying by default to sort Dates first (in ascending order) then the event names in ascending order. Is that possible with this plugin?

My sort list

`sortList: [[3,0],[1,0]]`

Does sort the dates column (3) but then it doesn't sort the even name column accordingly. If it's not clear (because I'm having a hard time trying to find good describing keywords to search :/ ) I want to sort the results of the original sort.

> Sort Date Ascending
>
> Then with the date still in Ascending Order, sort Event Names in
>   Ascending Order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the date column has an index of `3` (zero-based index, so it's actually the fourth column in the table) when there are only two columns, but...

Try the [`sortForce` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortforce). It forces (prepends) the sort of the targeted column(s) before any other column is sorted:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    sortForce : [[ 3,0 ]], // date column
    sortList  : [[ 1,0 ]]  // event column (user can still sort this descending)
});
```

Comment: Same problem happens here, it only sorts by the SortList option. I think the plugin isn't meant to do what I'm trying to do which is filter the results of the original sort into ascending (or descending) order. [An Example](http://pastebin.com/pdBYKUVH). Thanks for your help though, great plugin!

Comment: The `sortForce` option exists in the original tablesorter, but the code for it doesn't. You might want to try my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which does have it working.